# TF 2.0 SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy weird behaviour

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to do some customization using the `SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy` here, but I figured the value is not what I expect here when the sum of the probabilities is not equal to 1.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

cce = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(reduction=Reduction.NONE)
loss = cce(
  tf.constant([0, 1, 2]),
  tf.constant([[.9, .05, .05], [.5, .89, .6], [.05, .01, .94]]))
print(loss) # [0.10536056 0.8046684  0.0618754]

# What I expect for the second list is
-np.log(.89) # 0.1165338

# Validity check for first and third row
-np.log(.9) # 0.105360
-np.log(.94) # 0.061875
```

Am I misunderstanding something here? What is it doing under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at keras [implementation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/backend/numpy_backend.py#L333) of loss for numpy:

```py
def categorical_crossentropy(target, output, from_logits=False):
    if from_logits:
        output = softmax(output)
    else:
        output /= output.sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    output = np.clip(output, 1e-7, 1 - 1e-7)
    return np.sum(target * -np.log(output), axis=-1, keepdims=False)
```

as you can see, the output is devided by sum of all probabilities, so we have:

```py
-np.log(.89/(.5 + .89 + .6)) # 0.8046684549923527
```

Comment: Another question kind sir, won't that normalization affect the backpropagation if the sum is not equal to 1?

Comment: @HardianLawi categorical cross entropy loss is the choice for multi class classification in which usually we have a softmax layer at the top. For other cases like multi label classification in which we may have multiple active outputs, it's recommended to use binary cross entropy loss. Take a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/410165/38012) for more info.